# How to load image from writeable folder and assign to ImageView in Android?

Tags: android, imageview, bufferedreader

App save images to writeable folder and content is loaded in into a `BufferedReader` and want to assign it a an `ImageView`. What is the right approach to do it?

```
File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), body + ".image");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
icon. //What comes to here?
```

Comment: Ideally, use [an image-loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), or have your own background thread that works with `BitmapFactory` (e.g., `decodeFile()`, `decodeStream()`). I suppose you could use `decodeByteArray()` after reading in the bytes from the `BufferedReader`, but that seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathName);
icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: This will perform disk I/O and image decoding on the main application thread. Use `decodeFile()` in a background thread.

Comment: Or just use AsyncTask instead

Comment: Strange that I use the same pathName I used to save the image, but decodeFile returns null. SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null